# How can I get data from JSON Array in ExtJS?

Tags: json, extjs, frontend

I can't get value from Json Array in ExtJS

Example for my code:

```
var array = [];
array.push({"id": data.id, "name": data.name});
```

I tried below codes but I couldn't get it. How should I do?

```
array[0].data.data.id;
```

```
array[0].data.id;
```

```
array[0].data.data.get('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
array.items[0].data.id;
```